# Which type of file geodatabase format to use in FME?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, fme-form

What is the practical difference between the fgdb API format and fdgb ArcObjects in FME? When to use each of them in FME?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This FMEpedia article gives a brief comparison: [Comparison of FME readers and writers for SDE and Geodatabase](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Comparison-of-FME-readers-and-writers-for-SDE-and-Geodatabase).

This FMEpedia article also describes version compatibility for the various geodatabase readers and writers: [Notes on FME and Esri Versions and Compatibility](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Notes-on-FME-and-ESRI-Versions-and-Compatibility)

Notably, the File Geodatabase API is only able to work with 10.0 and newer geodatabases.

Use the ArcObjects format when you need to work with pre-10.0 GDBs or use any geodatabase features not supported by the File Geodatabase API (see pages 19-20 of [this presentation](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit11/papers/tech/the_file_geodatabase_api.pdf) for an overview).